# selecting date where date can be null

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public Nullable<DateTime> SpecificDate {get;set;}
  ....other properties
}
```

I'm writing a dynamic query that receive this object as a parameter and where I may or may not need the SpecificDate:

```
   if (condition){
       TheQuery = from....
                  where x.AppointDate.Date == TheObject.SpecificDate.Date
    }
```

However, when I write TheObject.SpecificDate. I'm not getting the intellisense to choose the .Date property.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: What is x.AppointDate.Date?  If it can't be null you will have a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write `TheObject.SpecificDate.Value.Date`.

However, be careful because if the date is `null` this will throw. You might want to check that `TheObject.SpecificDate != null` first.

Comment: Yes, that's why I have the if(condition) statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the SpecificDate.HasValue property

So your code would be something like:

```
if (condition){
   TheQuery = from....
              where TheObject.SpecificDate.HasValue && x.AppointDate.Date == TheObject.SpecificDate.Value.Date
}
```